# Сравнение объектов с одинаковым набором ключей и примитивами в качестве значений

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо сравнить два объекта, они прилетают с бэка.

Я делаю `JSON.stringify()`, и потом сравниваю с помощью `===`. Проблема в том что могут быть два объекта: `{age:16, name:1}`, `{name:1, age:16}` - получается что они не будут равны при сравнении, но по факту равны.

Как это решить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/4496422

Answer (score 5, accepted):

такой вариант сработает если у вас одинаковое количество ключей

```
const arg = {age:16, name:1}
const arg2 = {name:1, age:16}
const isEquals = Object.keys(arg).reduce((acc, rec) => {
    return acc && arg[rec] === arg2[rec]
}, true)

console.log(isEquals)
```

данный вариант включает проверку на количество ключей

```
const isEquals = (obj1, obj2) => {
    if(Object.keys(obj1).length === Object.keys(obj2).length) {
        return Object.keys(obj1).reduce((acc, rec) => {
            return acc && obj1[rec] === obj2[rec]
        }, true)
    }
    return false
}

console.log(isEquals({age:16, name:1}, {age:16, name:1, test:1}))
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то что мне нужно.

Comment: не верно, попробуйте добавить во второй объект третье свойство

Comment: @PROCODE проверьте еще раз, это не верный вариант, я выше написал сбойный сценарий

Comment: нужно проверять кол-во ключей, а еще если среди значений будет NaN проверка так же не пройдет,

Comment: для меня это сработало...

Comment: @PROCODE а если прилетят такие объекты, они для Вас равны должны быть или нет? {age:NaN, name:1}, {age:NaN, name:1}

Comment: такие не могут прилететь, но спасибо, ваш ответ тоже полезный

Comment: @PROCODE ну и вложенные объекты, конечно же тоже никогда не прилетят

Comment: @Stranger in the Q NaN - это спекуляция, которая никогда ничему не будет равна.

Comment: @DD_N0p да, именно по этому в сложных решениях на это отведена отдельная проверка

Comment: @DD_N0p Вы же понимаете, что Вы отвечаете не конкретному человеку, а пополняете базу знаний, кто-то скопирует не глядя Ваш код себе в проект и потом будет ловить ошибки, если пишете ответ - пишите развернуто, какие могут быть проблемы и подводные камни

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я исправил заголовок вопроса, чтобы программисты не обманывались простым решением