# как объединить объекта но при этом и их значения array

Tags: javascript

```
const service  = {var1: 'string',var2: ['1','4','3']}
const mango    = {var1: 'string',var2: ['1','2']}
```

если я сделаю так

```
const data = Object.assign({}, service, mango)
```

то var2 будет `['1','2']`
а если так

```
const data = Object.assign({}, mango, service)
```

то var2 будет `['1','4','3']`

но нужно получить `['1','4','3','2']`

возможно ли это при помощи ***Object.assign*** ?

Comment: При помощи одного только `Object.assign` нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, но выглядеть будет страшновато.

```js
const service  = {var1: 'string',var2: ['1','4','3']}
const mango    = {var1: 'string',var2: ['1','2']}

const data = Object.assign({}, service, mango, 
    {var2: [...new Set([...service.var2, ...mango.var2])]}
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

То есть вручную восстанавливаете перетёртое свойство с необходимой вам стратегией.

---

Если нужно более общее решение, рекомендую найти готовое в [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge)

Comment: и так - для каждого ключа на каждом уровне вложенности. здорово, чо

Comment: Ну так, можно, конечно, и функцию написать для deepMerge, но иногда этого достаточно)

Comment: другой программист введёт в google "как объединить объекты javascript" (частично совпадает с заголовком вопроса), скопирует твоё решение и оно не будет работать так, как он ожидает. от таких ответов никакой пользы в базе знаний

Comment: Не нужно говорить, какие ответы бесполезны, нужно добавлять свои полезные. И минусы ставить, они как раз для этого.

Comment: @nörbörnën, а программист перед копированием ответа может еще и сам вопрос прочитать? ну чтоб как раз вот этого "не будет работать" не было :)))

Comment: почитайте диалог под ответом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194347/2659

Comment: Почитал, вы решили повторить этот диалог тут? Вынесите лучше это обсуждение на Мету

Comment: Теперь видимо на каждый вопрос «Как записать значение в переменную» нужно в ответе писать фреймворк по помещению значений в переменные. Лишь бы парень с гугла не скопировал в неправильный environment